# Arranging categories with sub-categories correctly in Android app?

Tags: android, performance, android-studio, memory-management, main-activity

I am developing an Android app, which has around 6 categories. Every category, has 3 sub-categories each, with same name.

So, how can I arrange the categories in a way, to save long lines of codes. That means less number of activities. Here, I am demonstrating, with an example:

Category 1:
- Add
- Edit
- Delete

Category 2:
- Add
- Edit
- Delete

Category 3:
- Add
- Edit
- Delete

Category 4:
- Add
- Edit
- Delete

Category 5:
- Add
- Edit
- Delete

Category 6:
- Add
- Edit
- Delete

So, I don't want to show the sub-categories "Add-Edit-Delete" six times each for 6 categories, I just want it to be visible for one time on the "Main Activity".

For example,

If I am clicking on "Category 3" - It should ask me on the same activity to "Add or Edit or Delete". Let's say, on clicking, "Add", it should read, "Category 3 - Add" sub-category and rest the procedure goes on.

Can this be possible? I tried with popup-menu, but through this, I have to add "Add-Edit-Delete", separately for each category with separate UI, which isn't good.

What I can do for that?